# Re-Arrange Panels After Hiding One VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a windows forms app that is very complex. What I am trying to do now is if different buttons are clicked to disable some panels but shift all the other panels underneath of it up so it looks in order. I am having such a hard time with this. I wanted to develop a function that passes in a Panel that is getting disabled and a list of all other panels underneath of it and using recursion rearrange all the panels. This function works but it does not take in consideration if one panel has a height bigger than the other it leaves extra spaces between the two panels. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub whatever(ByVal panel As Panel, ByVal list As List(Of Panel))
    Dim temppanel As Panel = New Panel()
    For Each item As Panel In list
        temppanel.Location = New Point(temppanel.Location.X, item.Location.Y)
        item.Location = New Point(item.Location.X, panel.Location.Y)
        list.Remove(item)
        whatever(temppanel, list)
        If list.Count = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Image**

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/panelsz.png/

Comment: Screen shot might help explain what's going on here.  How are you first calling this `whatever` function in regards to intializing that list?

Comment: The 'whatever' function gets called whenever the specific button gets clicked. Based on a button I know what panel to not display anymore. I than loop and find all the panels that are under the panel that is getting not displayed anymore and I store all those panels into a list where than I call whatever function with a panel that is not getting displayed any more and the list of all other panels that need to be shifted. I hope that answered your question.

Comment: When you say "under" do you mean underneath in the z-order, or ones that fall at a vertically "lower" position on the screen?  Also, don't pass the Panel to your function if all you are doing is getting a location from it, pass a Point (or Rectangle if you need all the coords) instead.

Comment: sorry I mean Vertically Lower Position On The Screen.

Comment: @tcarvin Because I am doing this using recursion I pass the previous panel to get the coords from. I really dont know what is the best way of doing this and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FlowLayoutPanel probably is more appropriate for this, but here is a general method to do what I think you are looking for:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                          Handles Button1.Click
  ToggelPanel(Panel2)
End Sub

Private Sub ToggelPanel(ByVal whichPanel As Panel)
  Dim startPoint As New Point(10, 10)
  whichPanel.Visible = Not whichPanel.Visible

  For Each pnl As Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)(). _
                           Where(Function(x) x.Visible). _
                           OrderBy(Function(x) x.TabIndex)
    pnl.Location = startPoint
    startPoint.Y += pnl.Height + 4
  Next
End Sub
```

Replace `Me` with the parent container if these panels are not in `Me`.

---

If using .net 2.0 where LINQ is not available, the function would look something like this:

```
Private Shared Function CompareTabIndex(ByVal p1 As Panel, ByVal p2 As Panel) _
                                        As Integer
  Return p1.TabIndex.CompareTo(p2.TabIndex)
End Function

Private Sub ToggelPanel(ByVal whichPanel As Panel)
  Dim startPoint As New Point(10, 10)
  whichPanel.Visible = Not whichPanel.Visible

  Dim panels As New List(Of Panel)
  For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    If TypeOf Me.Controls(i) Is Panel Then
      If Me.Controls(i).Visible Then
        panels.Add(Me.Controls(i))
      End If
    End If
  Next

  panels.Sort(New Comparison(Of Panel)(AddressOf CompareTabIndex))

  For Each pnl As Panel In panels
    pnl.Location = startPoint
    startPoint.Y += pnl.Height + pnl.Margin.Bottom
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the quick answer. Do you know of a best way to figure out the spacing between each panel like in the image dynamically because they might not be the same?

Comment: @Nick I arbitrarily picked 4 pixels as my space.  You can increase that if you want.  What determines the spacing though?  I guess you can set each panel's `Margin.Bottom` value to the amount of space it needs, then change it to `startPoint.Y += pnl.Height + pnl.Margin.Bottom`.

Comment: this works very well but I noticed a problem. The Code that I am updating is in Framework 2.0 which Linq will not be available. :( this makes me mad.

Comment: @Nick I added a non-linq version.